# How to remove an option in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I  do not understand why this is not working? And not removing the small option!

I have the script:

```
<script>
var quantity_in_stock_s = 0


if ( quantity_in_stock_s === 0)
{

var S = document.getElementById("S");
document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(S);

}

</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<form>
<select id="mySelect">
<option id="S">Small</option>
<option id="M">Medium</option>
<option id="L">Large</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Is this wrong?!! :

```
</head>
<body>


<form>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option id="S">Small</option>
  <option id="M">Medium</option>
  <option id="L">Large</option>
</select>

</form>
<script>

   var quantity_in_stock_S = 0
   var quantity_in_stock_M = 0
   var quantity_in_stock_L = 0

function deleteOption1(){
      if ( quantity_in_stock_S === 0)
   {
     var S = document.getElementById("S");
     document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(S);
   }

}

function deleteOption2(){
      if ( quantity_in_stock_M === 0)
   {
     var M = document.getElementById("M");
     document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(M);
   }

}

function deleteOption3(){
      if ( quantity_in_stock_L === 0)
   {
     var L = document.getElementById("L");
     document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(L);
   }

}


window.onload = deleteOption1;
window.onload = deleteOption2;
window.onload = deleteOption3;


</script>
```

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KG8v3/

Comment: It's working..http://jsfiddle.net/kakarikos/bFwHd/

Comment: Quick! More JsFiddles!

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It seems like [there is no issue with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Wxr4J/) at all.

Comment: Move your script to below the rendered markup... Shouldn't affect execution, but at least it's consistent.

Comment: Sorry guys I literally can't tell what is wrong can you look at my whole HTML page above under Is this wrong?!!

Comment: @maxmitch did you change `window.load` to `window.onload` as mentioned in my answer? Is it still not working?

Comment: Edited my answer - you dont have a `<html>` or `<head>`

Comment: @Neurofluxation I just shortened it a bit....

Comment: What Browser are you using?

Comment: I assume it's fixed then @maxmitch

Comment: Sorry @Neurofluxation Can you have a look at my code again and see why it is only deleting the Large option not all of them... Thanks

Comment: @maxmitch - answered, but you really shouldn't of accepted an answer if it was wrong... [edit] just edited my answer

Comment: @Neurofluxation The question I asked first he answered correctly! I was just wanting to know a little bit more! Thanks again! Big help.

Comment: Edited again with a complete script revision.

Comment: Edited AGAIN with an Object Oriented approach ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `window.onload = deleteOption;` and not `window.load = deleteOption;`

Answer (score 1):

If fact, here's a revised script:

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option id="S">Small</option>
    <option id="M">Medium</option>
    <option id="L">Large</option>
  </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var quantity_in_stock_S = 0
  var quantity_in_stock_M = 0
  var quantity_in_stock_L = 0

  function deleteOptions() {
   if ( quantity_in_stock_S === 0) {
     var S = document.getElementById("S");
     document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(S);
   }
   if ( quantity_in_stock_M === 0) {
     var M = document.getElementById("M");
     document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(M);
   }
   if ( quantity_in_stock_L === 0) {
     var L = document.getElementById("L");
     document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(L);
   }
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    deleteOptions();
  };
</script>
```

Or... if you wanna go `Object Oriented`:

```
  <form>
      <select id="mySelect">
        <option id="S">Small</option>
        <option id="M">Medium</option>
        <option id="L">Large</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var Stocks = {
        SmallStock: 0,
        MediumStock: 0,
        LargeStock: 0,
        StockCheck: function() {
          if (Stocks.SmallStock === 0) {
            var S = document.getElementById("S");
            document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(S);
          }
          if (Stocks.MediumStock === 0) {
            var M = document.getElementById("M");
            document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(M);
          }
          if (Stocks.LargeStock === 0) {
            var L = document.getElementById("L");
            document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(L);
          }
        }
      };
      window.onload = function() {
        Stocks.StockCheck();
      };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a function and then call that function on window load or **as per your requirement**:

```
function deleteOption(){
   var quantity_in_stock_s = 0
   if ( quantity_in_stock_s === 0)
   {
     var S = document.getElementById("S");
     document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(S);
   }
}

window.load = deleteOption;
```

Comment: I would like the understand why he **needs** to create a function. This could clearly be an anonymous function, or not a function at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not working, the reason is that you have put it in between your `<head></head>` tags without binding it to a window/document load event ([`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload?redirect=no)).

try putting the same code **right before the `</body>`** closing tag. Don't forget to put it between `<script></script>` tags.